# Avoiding conditional code compilation

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Google C++ Style Guide (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Preprocessor_Macros) says:

"Instead of using a macro to conditionally compile code ... well, don't do that at all"

Why is it so bad to have functions like

```
void foo()
{
    // some code

#ifdef SOME_FUNCTIONALITY
    // code
#endif

    // more code
}
```

?

Comment: I've noticed most people on this site don't like the google style guide, but I would still say don't use this unless absolutely necessary because c++ template's are a much more powerful preprocessing tool than macros

Comment: how else would you write platform dependent code?

Comment: @yngum- You could have several different source files and use Makefiles or other build tools to select which ones to build based on the platform.

Comment: Don't use the Google C++ style guide.

Comment: [Read This](http://doc.cat-v.org/henry_spencer/ifdef_considered_harmful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe some the arguments against it go:

- `#ifdef` cuts across C++ expression/statement/function/class syntax. That is to say, like `goto` it is too flexible for you to trust yourself to use it.
- Suppose the code in `// code` compiles when `SOME_FUNCTIONALITY` is not defined. Then just use `if` with a `static const bool` and trust your compiler to eliminate dead code.
- Suppose the code in `// code` *doesn't* compile when `SOME_FUNCTIONALITY` is not defined. Then you're creating a dog's breakfast of valid code mixed with invalid code, and relevant code with irrelevant code, that could probably be improved by separating the two cases more thoroughly.
- The preprocessor was a terrible mistake: Java is way better than C or C++, but if we want to muck around near the metal we're stuck with them. Try to pretend the `#` character doesn't exist.
- Explicit conditionals are a terrible mistake: polymorphism baby!
- Google's style guide specifically mentions testing: if you use `#ifdef`, then you need two separate executables to test both branches of your code. This is hassle, you should prefer a single executable, that can be tested against all supported configurations. The same objection would logically apply to a `static const bool`, of course. In general testing is easier when you avoid static dependencies. Prefer to inject them, even if the "dependency" is just on a boolean value.

I'm not wholly sold on any argument individually -- personally I think messy code is still occasionally the best for a particular job under particular circumstances. But the Google C++ style guide is not in the business of telling you to use your best judgement. It's in the business of setting a uniform coding style, and eliminating some language features that the authors don't like or don't trust.

Answer (score 4):

As they say in the doc you linked to:

> Macros mean that the code you see is not the same as the code the compiler sees. This can introduce unexpected behavior, especially since macros have global scope.

It's not too bad if you have just one conditional compilation, but can get quick complicated if you start having nested ones like:

```
#if PS3
  ...
#if COOL_FEATURE
  ...
#endif
  ...
#elif XBOX
  ...
#if COOL_FEATURE
  ...
#endif
  ...
#elif PC
  ...
#if COOL_FEATURE
  ...
#endif
  ...
#end
```